# How to handle array list in a dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, oracle10g

I want to create a dynamic query to handle array list.

```
create or replace TYPE p_type IS table of varchar2(4000) ;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc_sk(
    p_class_array IN p_type,
    p_emp_record OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
  lv_stmt VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  lv_stmt          := 'Select * from dept where deptno = 10 ';
  IF(p_class_array IS NOT NULL) THEN
    lv_stmt        := lv_stmt || 'AND dname IN (select column_value from table(' || p_class_array ||'))';
  END IF;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_stmt);
  OPEN p_emp_record FOR lv_stmt;
END;
```

It gives a compilation error

> Error(9,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored Error(9,23): PLS-00306: wrong
>   number or types of arguments in call to '||'

Please help

Comment: There are many more conditions so I want the sql to be used dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`MEMBER OF` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjcol.htm#sthref512):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc_sk(
    p_class_array IN p_type,
    p_emp_record OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_emp_record FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   dept
    WHERE  deptno = 10
    AND    ( p_class_array IS EMPTY OR dname MEMBER OF p_class_array );
END;
```

Comment: Recently I have used 'member of' instead of 'select from table()' and the member of was extremely slower

Comment: @Mottor you can also use `OR dname IN ( SELECT * FROM TABLE( p_class_array ) )` if that is causing a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind the parameter  `p_class_array` .In dynamic SQL you would prefix them with a colon (:). If you use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `OPEN ... FOR`, you will bind your parameters via position to avoid sql injection.

Also note that in your `Select` statement you are doing `*`, so while execution you must declare individual variable to hold the outcome. To aviod mistake you must declare the column name in the select statement as shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc_sk(
    p_class_array IN p_type,
    p_emp_record OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
  lv_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  lv_stmt          := 'Select deptno,dname from dept where deptno = 10 ';
  IF(p_class_array.count > 0) THEN
    lv_stmt        := lv_stmt || ' AND dname IN (select column_value from table(:p_class_array))';     
  END IF;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_stmt);
  OPEN p_emp_record FOR lv_stmt using p_class_array;
END;

/
```

Execution:

```
SQL> Select * from dept ;

SQL> /

    DEPTNO DNAME
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        10 CTS
        20 WIPRO
        30 TCS

SQL> DECLARE
   vr   p_type:= p_type();
   x    SYS_REFCURSOR;
   z    VARCHAR2(10);
   z1   number;
BEGIN
   vr.extend(2);
   vr (1) := 'CTS';
   vr (2) := 'TCS';
      test_proc_sk (vr, x);

   LOOP
      FETCH x INTO z1,z;

      EXIT WHEN x%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (z ||'  ' ||z1);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
SQL> /
Select deptno,dname from dept where deptno = 10  AND dname IN (select column_value from table(:p_class_array))
CTS  10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I want to select all the columns. I am getting the sql query as Select dname from dept where deptno = 10  AND dname IN (select column_value from table(:p_class_array)). it is not using the bind variable

Comment: Then you need to either make and object of type of your `DEPT` table or in your PLSQL declare a variable of type of your table.

Comment: `then selecting the data in a varchar variable.` OP doesn't select data into a `varchar` variable.  `lv_stmt` `varchar` variable contains `select` statement itself not the result. OP's simply trying to concatenate varchar and nested table, thus the error.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov..Yes..agreed. OP has to decalre all the variables to capture the column values.

Comment: OP returns result(not processing it) of the query as a cursor. It'll be up to a calling pl/sql block, or a client app to process the result. So there is no need for declaring any local variable to hold the result of the query

Comment: @user2190186. Its using the bind variable. See the output.